# My custom check codeigniter doesn't work

Tags: codeigniter, validation

Form validation class I put the code,

```
public function custom($str)
{
        if ( ! is_array($str))
        {
                return (trim($str) == '')? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
                return ( ! empty($str));
        }
}
```

In the form validation land I put:

```
$lang['custom'] = "É necessário aceitar os %s";
```

And the controller class the code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('termos','TERMOS E CONDIÇÕES','custom');
```

And it doesn't work, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Codeigniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks), when you want a custom function as a validation rule, you must prefix it with `callback_`, so your rule would look like this :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('termos','TERMOS E CONDIÇÕES','callback_custom');
```